# Why the standard deviation of the sample mean is calculated as $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

According to Wikipedia, the standard deviation of a sample mean is calculated as follows $$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Why is that? Why do we need to divide the standard deviation of the population by the square root of $n$ (which should I think be the size of the sample)? Why should that make sense?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on that particular detail, with derivation, is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample mean is defined by
$$
\overline X=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k.
$$
If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are indepedent and identically distributed random variables, the variance of the sample mean is given by
$$
\operatorname{Var}\overline X=\frac1{n^2}\cdot n\operatorname{Var}X_1=\frac{\sigma^2}n,
$$
where $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}X_1$. The standard deviation is then given by
$$
\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\overline X}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}.
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are assumed to be identically distributed, we have that $\operatorname{Var}X_1=\operatorname{Var}X_2=\ldots=\operatorname{Var}X_n=\sigma^2$.